# Supwerpoered SDK AdvanceAudioPlayer Seek is not working on Android

Tags: android, audio, seek, superpowered

working with SuperpoweredAudvanceAudio Player to seek position when playing file. seeking is done from android context. i checked CrossExample of Android and it reflects me that seek operation is done in LoadSuccess callback, which seems to be Superpowered's thread context. i am facing problem of not seeking player playing file position using superpowered SDK while playing audio. so, during playing is inprogress & seek to some position, is it valid scenario using Superpowered SDK for android? below is the code that i used in LoadSuccess callback to seek, but it is not working.

```
        case SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess: {
        player->play(true);
        RCLog::GetInstance()->PrintLog(RCLOG_INFO, "%s : SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess", __FUNCTION__);
        if( isSeekRequired ){
            isSeekRequired = false;
            RCLog::GetInstance()->PrintLog(RCLOG_INFO, "%s : Seeking...", __FUNCTION__);
            player->seek( seekPer );
        }
        PlayerStatus(event);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seek() takes a percentage, a double between 0..1

setPosition() takes milliseconds